# phpmailer - error sending one message after another

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am just starting out with `phpmailer` and have managed to get it to send an email using:

```
require ('mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require_once('mail/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host       = "host"; 
$mail->Port       = 25;                  
$mail->Username   = "noreply@host"; 
$mail->Password   = "xxx";
$mail->From      = 'noreply@host';
$mail->Subject   = 'Report';
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = " ..... html .....";
$mail->AddAddress($recipient);
return $mail->Send();
```

Email sends and receives without a problem.

I want to send different messages to different recipients and so I copied and pasted the code from **$mail** to **return $mail** and pasted it immediately after the last line shown here. The first email is still received but the second email is not. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: From where are you returning? Is this in a function?

Comment: Remove the `return` - this will stop the rest of your script executing.

Comment: @Mike F got it I think. If this code is inside a function or a method, the execution of the funcion end at the return command and nothing under it will be executed

Comment: Got it!! And the answer was I indeed was missing something obvious. Thanks to you all.